# can i map domain name ec2-instance without use route53?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Can I map my aws-ec2 - instance to GoDaddy domain name without using route53?
route53 per mapping 0.5$. can you anyone know any idea about that?

Answer (score 3):

Using GoDaddy you can add an DNS A Record to your domain that would point to your EC2 public IP

https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238

In case you're wondering what's an A Record - taken from https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/

> What’s an A record?
>   An A record maps a domain name to the IP address (Version 4) of the computer hosting the domain. An A record is used to find the IP address of a computer connected to the internet from a name.
>
> The A in A record stands for Address. Whenever you visit a web site, send an email, connect to Twitter or Facebook, or do almost anything on the Internet, the address you enter is a series of words connected with dots.
>
> For example, to access the DNSimple website you enter www.dnsimple.com. At our name server there’s an A record that points to the IP address 208.93.64.253. This means that a request from your browser to www.dnsimple.com is directed to the server with IP address 208.93.64.253.
>
> A Records are the simplest type of DNS records, and one of the primary records used in DNS servers.
>
> You can do a lot with A records, including using multiple A records for the same domain in order to provide redundancy. Additionally, multiple names could point to the same address, in which case each would have its own A record pointing to that same IP address.
>
> The DNS A record is specified by RFC 1035.